# Cucumber test report from Rakefile

Tags: ruby, cucumber, rakefile, test-reporting

I have a set of Ruby/Cucumber tests. All tests run successfully when run in an IDE.

When I execute tests using this CLI command, the tests run and a test report is generated.

`$ cucumber --format progress --format html --out=features_report.html -r features --tags '@this or @that' features`

I need to execute the tests from a Rakefile in order to run tests in parallel. I can run them calling the Rakefile below with `rake local`

```
desc 'Run the functional test suite locally'
  task :local do

test_args = ["-n", '1', 
             "-o" "-t '@this or @that'",
             "--type", 
             "cucumber", 
             '--',
             '-f',
             'progress', 
             '--',
             'features',]

    ParallelTests::CLI.new.run(test_args)
  end
```

But I can't figure out where the extra options/arguments that generate a test report go.

If I group the report bits in the Rakefile as they are in the working CLI command

```
             'progress',
              '-f',
              'HTML', 
             '--out',
             'first.html',
```

I get this error:

```
Error creating formatter: HTML (LoadError)
```

Or, if I do this `"-o" "-t '@this or @that' --out first.html --format HTML",`

I get this:

```
All but one formatter must use --out, only one can print to each stream (or STDOUT) (RuntimeError)
```

Where in the test_args do the arguments that generate a test report go and what do they look like?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `profile` in the `cucumber.yml` file and pass the arguments under profile as shown below.

```
default:
  --no-source --no-color
  --format progress --format html --out=features_report.html
```

Now run your rake task as is, cucumber will pick the arguments from `cucumber.yml` file and generates the report.